# "cabal install" rebuilds built binaries and ignores "include-dirs:"

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a cabal based project with a cabal file fragment like this:

```
...
  include-dirs:
    include
...
```

and I have `.h` files (C headers) in this `include/` directory, my project directory looks like:

```
...
  `--- include/
         `--- one.h
         `--- two.h
         `--- three.h
...
myproject.cabal
cabal.project
...
```

My `cabal.project` has:

```
...
program-options
  -- this works for "cabal build": without it, the build fails
  ghc-options: -Lclib/mylib -mylib
```

and when I run `cabal build --with-compiler=...` everything is built OK (multiple binaries). Now I want to put build binaries in some folder. I suppose I should use `cabal install` for it?

But when I try `cabal install --with-compiler=...` I get errors that `.h` files cannot be found. Then I added more options to this command line: `cabal install --with-compiler=... --cabal-file=myproject.cabal --project-file=cabal.project` but I get the same error again.

How to put binaries in some folder (like `stack` does it with `--copy-bins --local-bin-path ...`)? Why does `cabal install ...` try to rebuild already built binaries and ignore cabal+project files? I suggest that it ignores them because building (vs. `install`) passes and it finds `.h`-files successfully.

PS. To be honest, the error comes from `gcc` when it compiles file like `/Something_hsc_make.c` which is `Something.hsc` converted to `.c` as I understand.

Comment: Sounds like a `cabal install` bug, which you may want to report on their GutHub (under `haskell/cabal`). Meanwhile, you can use `cabal list-bin <target>` to get the path to a desired executable and use it to copy the binary to a desired place using your shell.

Comment: For submitting a bug, a GitHub repo with a reproducer may be helpful.

Comment: `-Lclib/mylib -mylib` doesn't look right. Perhaps it was actually something like `-Lclib -lmylib`? But if so I think you probably should be playing with either the `extra-libraries`/`extra-foreign-libraries` or `c-sources` fields in your cabal file instead. Are your `.h` files listed in your cabal file's `extra-source-files`? More generally: this badly needs a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Our project is big and close-source so I still have not opened issue due to a reproducible example :) `extra-foreign-libraries` as I understood is for libs with source? Mine are without source (.so/.dll), they are not C even tbh.